# Can I find the source code filename and line number range of a particular C# function?

Tags: c#, bdd, roslyn

I'm working on a BDD-style automated testing library, and it would be great if I could include the *source code* of a failing test in the exception message.

Assuming I can climb the stack trace to find the function which best represents the test, can I use a tool like Roslyn to find the source code for that function?

By way of further explanation, I have tests which look like this:

```
        public void CannotChangePasswordIfCurrentPasswordIsIncorrect() {
        Given(
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.IsVisible,
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.CurrentPassword.Is("InvalidPassword"),
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.NewPassword.Is("ValidNewPassword"),
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.ConfirmPassword.Is("ValidNewPassword")
        );

        When(
            I.Click(App.ChangePasswordDialog.ChangePasswordButton)
        );

        Then(
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.Alert.IsVisible,
            App.ChangePasswordDialog.Alert.HasKeywords("current", "not correct")
        );
    }
```

If the test fails, I want to provide as much context in the exception message as possible, since I regard the exception as the UI for the test. I'm currently including things like links to screenshots and links to videos of the whole test, and it would be nice if I could also include the source code of the test (since it's pretty human-readable). It's a small thing, but there is a lot of mental context switching involved in debugging a test failure, and it would help not to have to go & look up what the test was trying to do.

NOTE: I'm not interested in a discussion of unit tests vs integration tests. These are integration tests, yes we have unit tests too.

You can assume:

- I have access to the source code, and can provide the path to the solution file
- I can climb the exception callstack to get a reference to a [System.Reflection.MethodBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase(v=vs.110).aspx)
   object which represents the function CannotChangePasswordIfCurrentPasswordIsIncorrect().
- I could provide pdb's if needed

So I basically need the filename and range of linenumbers where the source code for that function live.

Comment: What will you do with the source code?

Comment: The compiled code does not include the source code.  The stack trace shows you where to go look in the source code.  Stack traces work better with the PDB files, but there's no source code there.  I dunno what BDD has to do with anything here, but you can reverse engineer .NET to some degree with tools like reflector.  Then use the stack trace to manually navigate to the correct place.  Beyond that you need to create some custom code.  That would be a large project in and of itself.

Comment: You may try decompiling the code with Mono.Cecil, but i'm not sure this is practically doable (or useful), given that the decompiled code won't be the same that the source code.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - It may not be a crazy amount of work if all they want is an AST that represents the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20339199) has the information I was looking for.

Basically it's possible to use Roslyn to ask for the source of a particular function:

```
string GetMethod(string filename, string methodName)
{
    var syntaxTree = SyntaxTree.ParseFile(filename);
    var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
    var method = root.DescendantNodes()
                     .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                     .Where(md => md.Identifier.ValueText.Equals(methodName))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
    return method.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine this being a good idea. I also don't think it is possible.  Unless you're working with expression trees that haven't been compiled yet it's pretty much impossible to, at runtime, decompile the msil. Even if you could, some of the code would likely be represented entirely differently due to optimizations.

Comment: They could potentially read the file name and line number if they are running a debug build.

Comment: @ChaosPandion, that's actually pretty clever, given that you can read the stack trace and find the layer you're looking for.  still seems like a tall order for almost no benefit.

Comment: See my comment on the question. There may be a benefit we haven't considered.

Answer (score 1):

Do it the simple way - ask the user of your library to point you to the source code. That way you can look at the stack trace, go to the proper file and display the source line from there.

Comment: Yeah but that's what I'm asking - how to "go to the proper file and display the source line from there"

Comment: Well, the stack trace (in debug builds at least) contains the file name and line number. If you know where the source files are (ask the user to point you there), the rest is easy.

Comment: "The rest is easy" isn't all that helpful. Given a line number in a file, how can I pull out just the text of the function which includes that line number?

Comment: Ahhh, open the file, read all the lines and display the ones you want?

Comment: Yeah but that's the key. How to find the range of lines representing that function? You would need to know how to parse c#. I just found the answer - use Roslyn.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the source code, via the stack trace easily with

```
 var  stackTrace = Environment.StackTrace;
```

**Edit:**

The stack trace contains the code members and line of code of the Execution stack.
So you have the source code name.

**If you use **resharper***, you can do ctrl-c to copy this string to clipboard.*
Then ctrl-E T   inside visual studio and resharper will show a formnatted stack trace.
You can then just press on the source code error and it opens up the editor on the problem.

**Edit2:** So since you wanted the "source code extract" and the stack trace. My answer may not help.
But consider what is more useful.   I store the stack trace in a system log(db table). It has been more helpful than i care to admit ;-)
Depending on how encapsulated you code is.  The actual code throwing an exception might not be that useful. Anyway just my view.

Comment: this is still answering the wrong question.  he's asking if from his testing library he can access the compiled code that is being exercised.

Comment: the question title asked `Can I find the C# source code from an exception?` and yes you can access the source code from a stack trace.  The stack trace tells you the line of code.  A commercially available tool turns that effort into a click.  Only noted the roslyn function afterwards.

Comment: that is the title.  the question body and tags show the idea is to decompile code at runtime.

Comment: @nathangonzalez, good point accepted, but I still think the trace is more use than the piece of code that actually failed.

Comment: agreed.  i think the code is useless for the most part, just mainly stating the parameters of the question.

Comment: I did say "Assuming I can climb the stack trace to find the function which best represents the test" - don't need help with that, just need help getting from there to the source code.

Comment: yes you did that...btw Im curious how you plan to automatically decide which of the code members on the stack is at fault.  Even resharper only offers the stack trace formatted nicely. Dev analyzes the trace. Id be interested in the algorithm that knows which member on the call stack is at fault. Please share...

Comment: We just find the highest stack entry that is actually our code. Anything above that is the test runner.

    new StackTrace().GetFrames().Last(f => f.GetMethod().Module.Name.StartsWith("<ourmodulename>")).GetMethod();

Note that I'm not trying to find which code is at fault, just trying to find the code of the actual test.