# Unable to get method SyntaxTree.ParseFile in new nuget of Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, compilation, roslyn

I have installed nuget for `Roslyn` with `Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis -Pre` but i'm still unable to get the method `SyntaxTree.ParseFile` as I want to pass code in a `.cs` file

Any clue about why is it so ? How can I pass file here?

Comment: No such function exists.  You want the classes in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The API simply changed a little bit, one way to do it is :

```
var path = @"C:\...\SomeFile.cs";
using(var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(SourceText.From(stream), path: path);
}
```

Comment: To test whether the syntaxTree able to ParseText from the stream, you can use `syntaxTree.ToString()`

Comment: @Julien Roncaglia
Could you describe your solution in more detail?
**Description:**
**- 1.** I am in `VS` in `Nuget` looking for `Roslyn`. `Roslyn` isn't there.
**- 2.** I installed `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` from `Nuget`. `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` is not displayed in the `Links` of the project.
**- 3.** I installed `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` from Nuget. `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` does not appear in the `Links` of the project.

**Questions.**
**1.** How to implement your solution for the `Console` project `Framework-4.8`?