# Attribute to get method implementation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, attributes, custom-attributes

I have some methods(maybe in hundreds) in an assembly something like this:

```
public void SelectDepartment(string deptName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(deptName);
}
```

I wanted to read the whole method and write it in another file programmatically(A form has been designed for this operation). I thought that attributes can do the job and hence i created custom attribute like this:

```
[method: customplugin]
public void SelectDepartment(string deptName)
{           
    Console.WriteLine(deptName);
}
```

But the built in functionality fails to read the contents of the method. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi did you check this solution [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338068/getting-a-specific-method-source-code-from-cs-file-at-runtime

Comment: @kalidoss the post you've linked talks about source transformation... OP seem to be looking for direct byte code manipulation/parsing... (Probably XY-problem so).

Comment: Karthik Bhat, what makes you think attribute is useful for handling byte-code? Also consider clarifying your actual goal - there may be less insane ways to achieve that (more boring indeed).

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov - I'm open to any other ways.. The only parameter is that the method code is read at runtime and hence i thought attributes can do my work.

Comment: @Karthik Bhat Are you expecting to at runtime get the text as it exists in your .cs file to write to the other file?

Comment: Yes boredom.. I'd rather refer the method from a .dll

Comment: any solutions please??