# Is it possible to retrieve the variable name (not value) of a property using reflection?

Tags: c#, variables, reflection, properties, nameof

I am trying to retrieve the variable name of a property, instead of the value. I am currently using reflection, but if anyone has other suggestions it would be much appreciated.

I have three classes involved

A:

```
class A 
{
    public B bObject;

    int Number { return bObject.number; } //returns 3
}
```

B:

```
class B 
{   
    public int number = 3; 
}
```

C:

```
class C 
{
    public void myMethod() 
    {
        A aObject = new A();

        var aNumber = aObject
            .GetType()
            .GetProperty("Number")
            .GetValue(aObject, null);

        //this is the value. aNumber = 3.
        var objName = nameof(aNumber); //returns aNumber
    }
```

I want **objName to return the string "bObject.number,"** the variable that was called inside the property. Is this possible with my current setup, and if not, does anyone have recommendations?

I'd rather not have another method in B to return "nameof(bObject) + nameof(bObject.number)" then call both that method and the prop due to redundancy. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I would ask Why?  But its an interesting question...

Comment: Writing a module to adhere to third-party specifications, which requires that each attribute has a "tag" of some sort. The model is set up so that each prop's "tag" is also equal to the "bObject" name. Perhaps there's a bigger design issue here!

Comment: _I want objName to return the string "bObject.number," **the variable that was called inside the property**._ I don't believe this is possible. You're essentially trying to extract the name from the line of code that returned the value.

Comment: What happens when the compiler optimizes it to just `int Number => 3;`? Code inspection is best left for tools that run in the IDE, if you want to do that, I'd suggest looking at VS plugins and Rosyln code analyzers.

Comment: @stuartd it has been initialized right ? no reason its not avaible

Comment: @JanWillemHuising Actually if you took the code above as-is, this will throw a `NullReferenceException` because it is not initialized. Even if it was, the variable may be optimized out and possibly mangled when running in Release mode.

Comment: @JanWillemHuising A has been initialised, but bObject is still null and should be initialised in A's constructor.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do here is to retrieve the Number method's body and then remove the "return" and the ";" to get only the value you want.

There's a very good example here that shows how to get the body of a method as a string:
[Getting a specific method source code from .cs file (at runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338068/getting-a-specific-method-source-code-from-cs-file-at-runtime)

When that's done, you can just parse out the "return" and ";" to get what you want.

That's not extremely elegant, but it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom attribute and store strings like "bObject.number" in it. Then, attribute values are also accessible through reflection . https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/creating-custom-attributes

If you think it's too expensive to write same code twice, take a look at T4 templates https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx